# using keepalive in closeablehttpclient

Tags: java, http, tcpclient

I have some code as follow:

```
public class HttpUtil {
    public static String sendGetRequest(String url) {
        String result = null;

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }        
}
```

I want to know the connection is long connection as using keepalive in HTTP 1.1 when I using sendGetRequest. I want to use long connection in java.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for and what is the issue you are facing

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo, Shengfu wanted to know whether using CloseableHttpClient in a try-with-resources block would preclude them from leveraging the benefits of reusing HTTP connections.

Answer (score 2):

Default [Connection keep alive strategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) is keep alive **indefinitely**

> If the Keep-Alive header is not present in the response, HttpClient assumes the connection can be kept alive indefinitely.

To customize `CloseableHttpClient`'s keep-alive strategy  use `setKeepAliveStrategy`:

> ```
> CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
>     .setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy)
>     .build();
> ```